# How can I close this dialog windows using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I am pretty new in JavaScript and I have the following problem.

In a JSP page I call a JavaScript function that open a **dialog** windows (something like a popup) calling this JavaScript function:

```
pag_aperta = window.open(pagina, 'popUp_', DialParam);
```

where **pagina** is a variable that contains the name of the JSP page that have to be shown into the dialog.

So this is the content of the JSP page showed into my dialog (it works and this page is correctly showed into the dialog):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%
    // Per non far fare il caching...
    response.setHeader("pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
%>
<html>

    <head>
        <title><fmt:message key="titolo" /></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/seldoc.css">

        <script language="JavaScript" src="script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tables.js"></script>
    </head>

    <script>
        function gotoFrame(link){
            self.frames['change'].location.href = link;
            return;
        }
    </script>

    <body>

        <br/>
        <div class="blueheader16">
            <fmt:message key="vis_fatt_multiple_img" />
        </div>
        <br/>

        <table style="width:100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table class="table-cls" ID="Tabella2" style="width: 100%">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr><!--javascript:document.location.href='edi.do?serv=I.3'-->
                            <td style="text-align: center;  border-bottom: 0;">
                                <iframe name="change" src="about:blank" style="text-align: center; width: 100%; height: 380px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: center">
                                <!-- TASTO CHIUDI per chiudere la dialog: -->
                                <input style="color: #FFFFFF; font: bold 10px tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif" class="bottone" readonly="readonly" type="button" value=CLOSE" onclick="javascript: history.go(-1);">
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            gotoFrame('edi.do?serv=I.5&pk=<%=(String)request.getAttribute("pk")%>');
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see this page contains a button to close the dialog, this one:

```
<input style="color: #FFFFFF; font: bold 10px tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif" class="bottone" readonly="readonly" type="button" value=CLOSE" onclick="javascript: history.go(-1);">
```

To close the dialog it is used the JavaScript function **history.go(-1)** that don't works because from what I understand it take the user to the previous page (if it exist) and not close.

What can I do to close my dialog?

Comment: Try use pag_aperta.close();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing it from code in the "dialog," use

```
window.close();
```

...in response to a user event (like a click on a button).

If you're doing it from code in the page that *opened* the dialog, use `pag_aperta` instead:

```
pag_aperta.close();
```

(You'll need to make sure the variable is shared between the functions that use it.)

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly:
You wont to close the opened window stored in variable "pag_aperta".
try this:

```
pag_aperta.close();
```

Hope it helps